# Is there a multibyte-aware Postgresql Levenshtein?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, levenshtein-distance

When I use the **fuzzystrmatch levenshtein** function with diacritic characters it returns a wrong / multibyte-ignorant result:

```
select levenshtein('ą', 'x');
levenshtein 
-------------
       2
```

(Note: the first character is an 'a' with a diacritic below, it is not rendered properly after I copied it here)

The **fuzzystrmatch** documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html) warns that:

> At present, the soundex, metaphone, dmetaphone, and dmetaphone_alt functions do not work well with multibyte encodings (such as UTF-8).

But as it does not name the **levenshtein** function, I was wondering if there is a multibyte aware version of  **levenshtein**.

I know that I could use **unaccent** function as a workaround but I need to keep the diacritics.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your server, database, table and column settings? And what is the Unicode character exactly that you're trying to translate.

Comment: Use [UTF-8 codes](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex) (U+0105 for ą) instead of [combining characters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

Comment: @JayRizzo: Server and database encoding is **UTF8**. `\d TABLE` doesn't show the encoding of the table and columns, so I strongly assume it uses the setting for the DB.

Comment: @JayRizzo: About the character: See my new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56683034/11637535.

Comment: @klin: How can I do that? Please see my new question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56683034/11637535 where I elaborate on what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: This solution was suggested by @Nick Barnes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56688419/11637535) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56683034/11637535).

The 'a' with a diacritic is a character sequence, i.e. a combination of **a** and a combining character, the diacritic  ̨  : `E'a\u0328'`

There is an equivalent precomposed character **ą**: `E'\u0105'`

A solution would be to [normalise](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) the Unicode strings, i.e. to convert the combining character sequence into the precomposed character before comparing them.

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't seem to have a built-in Unicode normalisation function, but you can easily access one via the [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) language extensions.

For example:

```
create extension plpythonu;

create or replace function unicode_normalize(str text) returns text as $$
  import unicodedata
  return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str.decode('UTF-8'))
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Now, as the character sequence `E'a\u0328'` is mapped onto the equivalent precomposed character `E'\u0105'` by using `unicode_normalize`, the levenshtein distance is correct:

```
select levenshtein(unicode_normalize(E'a\u0328'), 'x');
levenshtein
-------------
           1
```

Comment: [Postgres now includes a `normalize` function (as of version 13)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.7.1.1.1).