# Postgresql levenshtein and precomposed character vs. combined character

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, levenshtein-distance, unaccent

I have Strings containing two similar looking characters. Both appear as small 'a's with an ogonek:

**ą**

**ą**

(Note: depending on the renderer they are sometimes rendered similarily, sometimes slightly differently)

However, they are different:

**Characteristics of the 1st character:**

In PostgreSQL:

```
select ascii('ą');
ascii 
-------
261
```

The UTF-8-encoding in Hex is: `\xC4\x85`

so it is a **precomposed character** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character)

**Characteristics of the 2nd character:**

In PostgreSQL:

```
select ascii('ą');
ascii 
-------
97
```

(same as character 'a')

That strongly indicates that the rendered character is combined out of two characters. And it is indeed:

The UTF-8-encoding in Hex is: `\x61\xCC\xA8`

So it is a combination of

a `\x61\`

and a **combining character** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), the separate ogonek:

̨ `\xCC\xA8`

I want to use PostgreSQL's **levenshtein** function to determine the similarity of words, and so I want treat both characters as the same (as it is of course intended by people who write the name of a distinctive entity either with the 1st or the 2nd character).

I assumed that I can use **unaccent** to always get rid of the ogonek, but that is not working in the 2nd case:

1st character: expected result:

```
select levenshtein('ą', 'x');
levenshtein 
-------------
       1
```

1st character: expected result:

```
select levenshtein(unaccent('ą'), 'x');
levenshtein 
-------------
       1
```

2nd character: expected result:

```
select levenshtein('ą', 'x');
levenshtein 
-------------
       2
```

2nd character: unexpected result:

```
select levenshtein(unaccent('ą'), 'x');
levenshtein 
-------------
       2
```

So, when I compare both characters with **levenshtein** and **unaccent**, the result is 1:

```
select levenshtein(unaccent('ą'), unaccent('ą'));
levenshtein 
-------------
       1
```

instead of 0.

How can I "get rid of the ogonek" in the 2nd case?

(How) can I use the UTF-8 codes of Strings to get the achieved result?

**Edit**: As @s-man suggested, adding the combining character to `unaccent.rules` would solve this particular problem. But to generally solve the ***precomposed character vs. combined character*** problem with **unaccent**, I would have to explicitly add/modify every missing/"misconfigured" combined character to/in the config.

Comment: Maybe you should check your configuration: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html Maybe both characters have different configs...

Comment: Yes, the combining character is missing in the config, so adding it would solve this particular problem. But to generally solve the _precomposed character vs. combining character_ problem this way, I would have to explicitly add every (missing) combining character to the config.

Comment: I updated the title and the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing accents will give you a Levenshtein distance of 0, but it will also give you a distance of 0 between `ą` and `a`, which does not sound ideal.

The better solution would be to [normalise](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) the Unicode strings, i.e. to convert the combining character sequence `E'a\u0328'` into the precomposed character `E'\u0105'` before comparing them.

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't seem to have a built-in Unicode normalisation function, but you can easily access one via the [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) language extensions.

For example:

```
create extension plpythonu;

create or replace function unicode_normalize(str text) returns text as $$
  import unicodedata
  return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str.decode('UTF-8'))
$$ language plpythonu;
```

And then:

```
test=# select levenshtein(unicode_normalize(E'a\u0328'), unicode_normalize(E'\u0105'));
 levenshtein
-------------
           0
```

This also solves the issue in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56676187), where the combining character was contributing to the Levenshtein distance:

```
test=# select levenshtein(unicode_normalize(E'a\u0328'), 'x');
 levenshtein
-------------
           1
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your answer to answer my previous, related question.

Comment: [Postgres now includes a `normalize` function (as of version 13)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.7.1.1.1).

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your configuration and add the missing characters manually at the config file as described in https://postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html

Comment: Thank you (esp. for your comment above). I upvoted the answer.

Comment: But as I wrote in the reply to your comment above and in my edit, I am aware that this would solve the problem. However, it is doubtful that I would be able (and willing) to add every missing character to the config. So hopefully there is an alternative solution.

Comment: I was just thinking: Maybe there is a comprehensive list useable for unaccent.rules that maps combining characters and corresponding precomposed characters  to the same target characters.

Comment: Yes maybe one can find such anywhere. But to create an own... How many characters we are talking about? 100? 1000? Hm, there are only a few "modifiers", accents, umlauts, maybe 10? Then there are only a few letters which can be modified: AEUOILSCGZ... Maybe creating it manually takes not too long time. Am I wrong? Adding some ligatures like ß or AE,...

Comment: You don't have to consider every combination of "modifiers" and "letters", it is sufficient to know the "modifiers": see my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This solution is based on @S-Man's suggestion to explicitly add missing characters to the `unaccent.rules` file.
>
> Note: A prerequisite of this answer is that the relevant **precomposed characters** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) are already mapped in the `unaccent.rules` file. If not, they have to be added also.

There are characters which are composed of multiple characters:

- a "basic" character (e.g. vowels like a, consonants like l)
- a **combining character** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), typically one diacritic like acute ( ´ ) or dot ( · )

The goal is to map a "multiple character" character on the containing "basic" character.

(assuming the corresponding precomposed characters are mapped to the "basic" character, which is the case in the original `unaccent.rules` file)

**unaccent** checks every character in a "multiple character" character for replacement, so it is not necessary to consider every combination of basic character and diacritic.

Instead the diacritics have to be mapped on [nothing]. This can be achieved by leaving the second column in the `unaccent.rules` file (https://postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) empty.

This is a list of diacritics for the Latin alphabet obtained from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic:
´
˝
`
̏
ˆ
ˇ
˘
̑
¸
¨
·
̡
̢
̉
̛
ͅ
ˉ
˛
͂
˚
˳
῾
᾿

Add to that the ogonek of the question, which is missing:
̨

Now (after a PostgreSQL restart, of course), **unaccent** maps "multiple character" characters on the "basic" character, as it does with precomposed characters.

Note: The above list may not be comprehensive, but should at least solve a good part of the "precomposed character vs. combined character" problem.

Comment: Diacritics have been added recently to unaccent.rules. If you download `unaccent.rules` from PostgreSQL 12 beta 1 it should already have your suggestion in. It will not be backported to previous versions to keep unaccent() results stable within major versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info!